# Autenticação de login por IP

Tags: php, auth

Estou criando um aplicativo PHP para autenticação de login:

```
$phpsessid = 'SID: ".SID."<br>session_id(): ".session_id()."<br>COOKIE: ".$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]';
file_put_contents("$ip","$phpsessid");
$m = "localhost/'.$ip.'";
$res = file_get_contents("$m");
$title=@$this->stribet($res,'SID:','<br>');
}
```

o `$phpsessid` vai conter os dados, horário, IP, conta logada, hora, etc.
Como fazer para verificar um IP na hora do login? Por exemplo:

```
IP=>Conta=>PHPSESSID
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando servidor proxy, o IP que você obterá será o do servidor proxy e não o endereço IP real do usuário. Exemplo:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Mas felizmente podemos fazer um refinamento adicional para obter resultados mais precisos. Os servidores proxy trazem no cabeçalho HTTP uma propriedade que armazena o IP original. Exemplo:

```
echo "Remote addr: " .$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "<br/>";

echo "X Forward: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] . "<br/>";

echo "Clien IP: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] . "<br/>";
```

Na hora do login faz-se uma comparação do usuário com o IP.

Comment: Só tome cuidado pois [`curl -H "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: '; DROP TABLE logins; --"`](http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2007/12/02/faking-the-unexpected/).